# Selenium timeoutexception with webdriver

Tags: python, selenium

First post on here and brand new to Python. I am trying to learn how to scrape data from a website. When you first load the website, a disclaimer window shows up and all I am trying to do is hit the accept button using the `browser.find_element_by_id`.

I am using the `webdriverwait` command to wait for the page to load prior to clicking the "Accept" button but I keep getting a `Timeoutexception`. Here is the code that I currently have:

```
from selenium import webdriver
#get the chrome webdriver path file
browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"C:/Program Files (x86)/Google/Chrome/Application/chromedriver.exe")
browser.get('http://foreclosures.guilfordcountync.gov/')

from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
#wait until element is loaded
wait = WebDriverWait(browser, 10)
wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "cmdAccept")))

element = browser.find_element_by_id("cmdAccept")
element.click()
```

Here is the error I keep getting:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Abbas/Desktop/Foreclosure_Scraping/Foreclosure_Scraping.py", line 33, in <module>
    wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "cmdAccept")))
  File "C:\Users\Abbas\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\wait.py", line 80, in until
    raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:
```

I believe it has something to do with the calling out the ID of the button itself from the website but I honestly do not know. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your attempts to locate the element are unsuccessful because of they are nested within an `iframe`. One must tell selenium to switch to the `iframe` that contains the desired element before attempting to click it or use it in any way.  Try the following:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
#get the chrome webdriver path file
browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"C:/Program Files (x86)/Google/Chrome/Application/chromedriver.exe")
browser.get('http://foreclosures.guilfordcountync.gov/')
browser.switch_to.frame(browser.find_element_by_name("ctl06"))
wait = WebDriverWait(browser, 10)
wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "cmdAccept")))
element = browser.find_element_by_id("cmdAccept")
element.click()
```

Comment: Nice answer.  As OP is a new user, I just wanted to make the explanation as clear as possible.

Comment: I am facing the same issue I want to access an element but i think it is nested within iframe. 
<iframe scrolling="yes" src="https://www.goinet.in/gonoshow/default.aspx" style="border: 0px none; margin-left:10px;min-height: 700px;   margin-top: 0px; width: 926px;">.
I wanted to know how do I switch to this iframe. 
browser.switch_to.frame(browser.find_element(<what to put here>). As this iframe does not have id or name

Comment: I figured out how to switch the iframe, here is the code if anyone is looking for.           
iframe = browser.find_element(By.XPATH, "//iframe")
browser.switch_to.frame(iframe)
pnr = browser.find_element(By.ID, 'ContentPlaceHolder1_txt_PNR')